# Publicly accessible URL throwing IOException

Tags: java, io, inputstream, urlconnection

I would like to access the link `http://www.nation.co.ke/business/seedsofgold/Egg-imports-from-Uganda-hatch-big-losses-for-farmers/-/2301238/2897930/-/dpeqesz/-/index.html`

The link is publicly accessible, and can even load using `curl`

But in Java code  it throws `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.nation.co.ke/business/seedsofgold/Egg-imports-from-Uganda-hatch-big-losses-for-farmers/-/2301238/2897930/-/dpeqesz/-/index.html`

This is the code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param url the HTML page
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String getPage(String url) throws IOException {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();

    String mime = conn.getContentType();
    if( !StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(mime, "text/html") ) {
        return null; // don't continue if not HTML
    }
    else {

        // read the response body, using BufferedReader for performance
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.defaultCharset()));
        int n = 0, totalRead = 0;
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        // read until EOF or first 16384 characters
        while (totalRead < 16384 && (n = reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            content.append(buf, 0, n);
            totalRead += n;
        }
        reader.close();

}
```

The error is thrown at:

```
       InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

The same code works fine with other URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
```

to your connection right after `URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();`. Many websites block the site access when no correct agent is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting HTTP 403 status code, it means access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason.

A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action.

You can refer [HTTP 403 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Comment: The 403 error occurred only when accessing via `URLConnection`. The page loaded properly in a browser and even via `curl`. For solution see answer by @ScreamingTree

Comment: You just need to add User-agent header.